# Are there any simulate software or patch of EPT(SLAT) for Intel Core 2 Duo CPU?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, intel

Are there any simulate software or patch of EPT(SLAT) for Intel Core 2 Duo CPU? 
Because I want to run Windows Phone 8 Emulator by Hyper-V on Windows 8.

Comment: Same for me. Very disappointing thing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible to "emulate SLAT", you just have to buy new PC, if you want to develop for Windows Phone 8.